# Why not allow shorter comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Surprisingly it seems no one asked this before.

Not long ago I asked a question on the site, and in a comment I was asked "what version of jQuery are you using?". The answer is obviously less than 15 characters. So I had to do something like this "I am using version 1.9.1" instead of just "1.9.1".

I see this a lot, so why not allow shorter comments?

I guess the idea is to force people to give more thorough comments and not just small quirks, but I think it reasonable to allow users with a ceratin amount of reputation to give shorter comments, because sometimes it just makes more sense and you don't really need 15 characters

Comment: In that situation it was likely the comment was left because you left out a piece of vital info from the question text itself. In such cases the best route to take is not to leave a comment with the brief bit of info but to add it into the question itself, making the question more useful. You can then leave a comment saying "I've updated my question with the relevant info" or something like that. If you had left "1.9.1" as a comment then it could've been overlooked or even deleted.

Comment: Heh.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @MrLister: How?

Comment: @juergend rightclick inspect element in chrome you'll get it

Comment: @AndersUP I did not find that when searching. But I think Servy's answer is better than the one in the link

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with writing whole sentences? I know most of us are SMS generation, but don't make it extreme. Writing one-sentence answer to a short question isn't THAT much work, and doesn't require enormous amounts of work, does it?

Comment: It's not a matter of much work, but sometimes shorter is better. I don't know, I thought it deserved a debate. @downvoters please add some helpful comments and don't just blindly downvote because you don't agree

Comment: I agree. Argh, but now I have to type a full sentence... The irony.

Comment: @AndersUP for agreeing there are upvotes here, not comments. It even says so in a comment's help text before you start writing :D Once again char limit worked as it should!

Comment: @yuvi here on meta downvotes are for "I do not agree" as well as "question is bad", personally I don't like that, but it is as it is

Comment: @Mołot My comment to agree is with Yuvi's comment that Servys answer here is better than the answers in the duplicate I link to. I just didn't @-mention him as he is the OP and get notification of the comment anyway. And, for the record, I had already voted on this page as well as the one I link to before your comment.

Comment: My question is why the @ portion of comments count towards the 15? Because then I can @ someone completely unrelated with a short comment.

Comment: it works­­­­­!­

Answer (score 16, accepted):

But your longer comment is better.  It's stand alone; i.e. it makes sense even if the earlier question is deleted, or wasn't noticed by the reader; it incorporates *context*.  It sounds to me like the character limit was doing its job.

Comment: That's true per my specific case, but sometimes a short comment makes more sense. And even in my case a short comment would not be completely out of context. It's right below another short comment asking what version I'm using - it does have context

Comment: @yuvi You've shown one example that indicates how the char limit is *beneficial*.  If you want to show that it should be removed you'd need to demonstrate that there are lots and lots of cases where it's harmful.  So far you haven't done that.  As I said in my answer, the earlier comment could be deleted, a reader could not see it, or if yours gets comment upvotes and his doesn't yours could be shown when his is not if there are enough total comments.  In all of those cases the context of your first example is lost (or at least less accessible).

Comment: I don't think my case demonstrates either, it's a matter of debate. However, your other point about upvoted comments floating upwards and not making sense is much more convincing to me.

Comment: Another point I just thought about (in your favor completely) is that short comment also support a chat-like dynamics in the comment section which I understand is not encouraged

Comment: It also avoids "+1" and "thanks" comments, which only add noise to a post.