# Bypassing minimum comment length with Soft hyphen - (ALT + 0173)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just posted this comment: [it works!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200115/why-not-allow-shorter-comments#comment636878_200115) and the source code is:

```
<span class="comment-copy">it works­­­­­!­</span>
```

It seems that nothing visible here but I used this character:`­` [alt + 0173], I knew this case is not common, but the JavaScript part can be improved to count readable characters only.

The HTML entity is: **`&shy;`** for that hidden character, its called [Soft hyphen (SHY)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html)

Comment: Related - [Bananas in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/bananas-in-comments) - no it isn't that smart.

Comment: I just posted this for improvements I don't know if its bug or expected behaviour

Comment: please don't play with it I will delete my question if so!

Comment: I'm still waiting for the punchline of the title. What can be achieved by passing comment?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137018/167534)

Comment: At least posting question like that returned "This post does not meet our quality standards."

Answer (score 3):

Why do some people have a problem with brevity?

A short post can be every bit as high-quality and effective as a longer one.

If someone used `Alt+0173` to make their brief post, they certainly aren't making short posts because of a lack of effort.

I see this as a good thing, not a fault.

Comment: I am not taking about why users uses this, I just posted to let developers know if its expected or not.

Comment: I would dispute something in this answer, but... tl;dr

Comment: @Shog9 tl;dr: Just do it.